# MSBuild publish dotnet core application

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

My setup is: I have a solution that had different dotnet4.6 applications (services) in it. Now we added a dotnet core project inside this solution. I can build and debug it, but this doesn't create an executable. In Visual Studio I can rightclick -> Publish... it. I created two profiles (x86 and x64) that should create nice binaries in /bin/Publish/x86 or /x64. In VS this works. The application is self-contained and works on different unprepared machines.

But now I Need to move that process to the buildserver. I messed around with `dotnet publish` but in the end i get stuck because other components of the solution are not clean dotnet core and so the build fails.
So I need to stick with MSBuild.

The current attempt is:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" NewProject\NewProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:UsePublishProfile=true /p:PublishProfile=x64Profile`.

This says it finished building successfully, but I don't see any results. Also it doesn't make any difference, if I remove all properties and just call msbuild and *.csproj. It just builds the new project in bin/Debug, as dll, not exe.

I also messed around with `p:PublishProfile="NewProject\Properties\PublishProfiles\x64Profile.pubxml"` and `/p:PublishUrl="NewProject\bin\Publish\x64"` but it doesn't change anything.

I read a few articles on SO, telling that VS doesn't just call msbuild with parameters but does internal API calls. Still, I need a solution. I need the build server to create an executable. Is there a way to trigger msbuild to create thath?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oh man, I searched for 2-3 days now. And - as always on StackOverflow - shortly after asking I found a working answer myself.

**tl;dr:**

Project.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>  
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <RootNamespace>Company.Toolset.Exporter</RootNamespace>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
...
```

MSBuild command:

`msbuild Project\Project.csproj -t:restore /t:Build;Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /p:PublishProfile=x86Profile /p:OutputPath=bin/Publish/x86` (and the same for x64)

**Explanation:**

I think it was the `dotnet build/publish` command that wanted me to change `TargetFrameworks` to `TargetFramework`. But for MSBuild this is wrong. And `dotnet` wasn't working here, as the solution is mixing dotnet core and dotnet framework. So that had to be fixed.

The `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` was needed by the command. I added it to the *.csproj because I know that I build for windows only (at the moment) and that I need both versions.

I don't really know why I needed this line   `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />` but without this publishing and using the PublishProfiles didn't work as expected.

**Links that helped me to get here:** (not sorted)

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901

https://github.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/issues/22

[How to Publish Web with msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild)

[ASP.NET Core Application (.NET Framework) for Windows x64 only error in project.assets.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842443/asp-net-core-application-net-framework-for-windows-x64-only-error-in-project)

[Configure MSBuild output path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633531/configure-msbuild-output-path)

Comment: Just my intuition here, but if you use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` instead of using the library SDK does that simplify your csproj?

Comment: The first line of this project file is problematic like the other comment indicated. You should not modify it to use `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` either, as that's a typical step for ASP.NET 4.x projects. This can be a misleading answer, as ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core projects should be treated differently and without so many hacks.

Answer (score 16):

I too had a nightmare with inconsistencies between builds from Visual Studio IDE and the `dotnet publish` command, that were only fixed by doing it using msbuild.exe instead. Also, using `/p:PublishProfiles=theXMLthatVSgenerates.xml` never worked, so I had to break out every option into the msbuild command line.

Here's what worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" C:\Users\xxxx\Source\Repos\netcore-agent1\CoreAgent1\CoreAgent1.csproj /t:Restore;Rebuild;Publish /p:PublishSingleFile=True /p:SelfContained=True /p:PublishProtocol=FileSystem /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp3.1 /p:PublishDir=bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\win-x64 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:PublishReadyToRun=False /p:PublishTrimmed=False
```

Comment: Been looking for this solution for a few days now - Seems that "dotnet publish" does not do the same as publishing from visual studio. This solved my problem - Thanks alot!

Comment: Solved my issue. It is important to point out, that when using the "/p:SelfContained=True "  also the RuntimeIdentifier has to be set. Example: "/p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64" // And yes, you had it already in your list of options.

Comment: Haha so true - Msbuild seems to ignore PublishProfiles parameter and carry on doing its own thing - not sure what's wrong but outside of VS it does NOT work as advertised.