# Visual Studio Clickonce Specific Target tab missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clickonce, .net-4.8

Following instructions in this link to deploy with Clickonce:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2019

I right click in the project and select Publish, and the Publish wizard opens, with the "Target" tab selected as expected, and I select "Folder" option. Then, when I click the "Next" button, it does not appear the "Specific tab", but it goes directly to "Publish location" tab. The problem with this is that I cannot select "Clickonce" anywhere because I do not see the "Specific target" tab, so there is no "Install location", "Settings", "Sign manifests" or "Configuration" tabs.

This is the expected tab that not appears:
[image]

And this is the screen I see (sorry, it is in Spanish):
[image]

It is a .NET Framework 4.8 project.

Why is Clickonce missing? What can I do to get the right screen in the wizard so I can use Clickonce?

Thank you

UPDATE: I have tried to update to .NET 5, and then magically ClickOnce appears in the Publish wizard. So, how can I use ClickOnce with net48 in a SDK scheme project? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Framework ClicOnce is not compatible with the SDK style projects, here the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/9#issuecomment-858820786) discussion. So the correct answer here would be: is not possible.

What you could do is either downgrade your csproj style to old version or update your project to a .net core 5 or use [cli msbuild to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581895/3568131).

Answer (score -1):

The "expected tab" is the update content for `.NET Core & .NET 5`. As you said, when you update the `target framework` to `.NET 5`, the tab will be shown.

If you are developing with `.NET Framework 4.8`, you still can right-click the project and click Publish. Because it will be published via ClickOnce bu default.

Or follow the steps `Project => Properties => Publish`.

Comment: Both ways, right-click and project -> properties, open the wizard without that tab. Now I am not sure that .NET Framework 4.8 with Sdk-style csproj is compatible with ClickOnce. Thank you

Comment: Well, you can try to suggest a feature [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?port=1025&fsid=afe62ef9-47ca-4eff-9ab6-6d857a4f2f9f&entry=suggestion).

Comment: As @Carlos states, this is not an answer for his exact question.